# Textviews are not positioned correctly in Android

Tags: android, textview, android-constraintlayout, seekbar

I want to position text views directly under a seekbar in Android. Unfortunately the shown layout in the emulator does not look correct altough in the layout editor the layout looks correct. You can see this on the screenshots[image]

There are two problems:

1. The textview on the left of the seekbar is to high altough in the layout editor it is on the same level as the seekbar
2. The labels for each point of seekbar are all too much on shifted onto the right side.

Here you have the XML-layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView50"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="41dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
        android:text="50"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/o_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView40"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView60"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="41dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
        android:text="60"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/o_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView50"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="245dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewS"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RButton"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.016"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.395" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/commentButton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="comment_Button"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.83"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/comment" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/comment"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.025"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.76" />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/o_button"
        android:layout_width="163dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#121212"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.87" />






    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup_Size"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.871"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">




        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/r_Button_Small"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
            android:text="@string/small"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.322"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.584" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/r_Button_Medium"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/Medium"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.962"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.583" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/r_Button_Large"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
            android:text="@string/Large"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.962"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.584" />

    </RadioGroup>


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="130dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="70dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
        android:popupBackground="#5fe0f5"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/spinner2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioGroup_Size"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:popupBackground="#5fe0f5"
        android:textSize="120sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/o_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/spinner1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.59"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/spinner1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioGroup_Size"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.44" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Spinner 1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/spinner1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.102"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewS" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
        android:text="Spinner 2"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/spinner2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:max="4"
        android:maxHeight="4dip"
        android:minHeight="4dip"
        android:progress="2"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/o_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.89"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Seekbar"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/seekBar"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.218"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView9"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.45" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView30"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="57dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="57dp"
        android:text="30"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/o_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView12"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView40"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="41dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
        android:text="40"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/o_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView30"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView70"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="70"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/o_button"
        android:layout_marginStart="42dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView60"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.1" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Can you tell me why this problem occurs? For me it is quite strange because in the layout editor everything is being displayed correctly and I do not understand why generally there are sometimes differences between the layouteditor and the layout on an emulator in Android. I'd appreciate every commment and would be thanful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I see here there are some constraint issues what you have set and what you are trying to achieve :-
In this :-

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="26dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:max="4"
    android:maxHeight="4dip"
    android:minHeight="4dip"
    android:progress="2"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/o_button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.89"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Seekbar"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/seekBar"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.218"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView9"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.45" />
```

You can see you have set your `Seekbar` textview top and bottom constraints to `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"` and `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView9"` change that to `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/seekBar"` and `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/seekBar"` This will make your `Seekbar textview` in center of your actual `seekbar`.

Now coming to the `values` section I see that you haven't set your views in your proper aligned manner so it's really hard to find which text view is set where from your xml code. Although I would suggest you take a `constraint` or `linear` layout with the same `width` of your `seekbar` and below `seekbar` and then set the text in that layout using `constraintWidthPercent`(if using constraint layout) according to the max values you have in your `seekbar`.

Comment: Thanks Mohammed Hanif for your answer. Basically I do not want to use a LinearLayout because then I would have many nested views and that gets complicated. So I do not understand how to implement your suggestion as I have already used a ConstrainedLayout. Further I have tried the attribute "android:constraintWidthPercent="60"" and other values on the textViews but it did not seem to have any effect.

Comment: You wrote "you haven't set your views in your proper aligned manner so it's really hard to find which text view is set where from your xml code. ". Do you use Android Studio? There you can just copy and paste my XML code into an XML file and then you will see how they are aligned and you will see that they are correctly aligned according to the Layout Editor. As you can see in the posted screenshots the alignment is correct for the value-textviews (I spent quite some time to align those textviews directly under the correct place of the seekBar).

Comment: Hey @VanessaF you can see in your xml you have declared your `textView50 ` and `textView60 ` on the first and then some other views and then comes your other `texviews` like `textView30` `40` and so on. How do you say that it is in proper format ?

Comment: Again coming to the `linear layout` it's good to have if you have that for fixed size like same of your `seekbar` size so that you can manage the layouts easily in that instead of calculating for each of them

Comment: did your `SeekBar` textview issue resolved ?

Comment: for using `"android:constraintWidthPercent="60"` you need to create a new `constraint layout` inside of your `layout` with the same size of your `seekbar`

Comment: Thanks Mohammed Hanif for your comments and efforts. I really appreciate it. Yes my seekbar textview issue was solved by your suggestion. Thanks a lot for that. However, I am still struggeling with the value-textViews

Comment: Did you check in Android Studio my code? Does the layout Editor not display the value-textViews in the correct way? This would be quite suprising because in my Android Studio Layout Editor they are being displayed correctly but strangely in the Emulator they are all shifted to the right. For me this is really weird because why does the Layout Editor display them correctly and in the Emulator they are at different positions. I spent quite some time to adjust the value-text Views using the Android Studio Layout Editor.

Comment: Hanif: You wrote "textView50 and textView60 on the first and then some other views and then comes your other texviews like textView30 40 and so on. How do you say that it is in proper format ? "
--> basically the order is not important as far as I understand. You just have to set the constraints correctly and according to the Android Studio Layout Editor they single text-views are exactly where they are supposed to be.

Comment: Hey @VanessaF I am afraid i won't be able to copy this and check in android studio. However you can use the below given library to achieve what you want :- https://github.com/warkiz/IndicatorSeekBar

Comment: Please do a upvote and accept the answer if it did help you so that others can find it easily.

Comment: Thanks Mohammed Hanif for your answer. Basically I do not want to use any third party library or code. Sorry. I did upvote your answer but I did not accept it as my question has not been solved. I still do not understand why my textViews are positioned correctly according Android Studio Layout Editor but displayed in a wrong way in the Emulator. According to the Layout Editor I aligned them all correctly.

Comment: The only issue which i think is in your constraints if you change your layout editor to some other device or in portrait then you might see different outputs in them as well due to constraints

Comment: Thanks Mohammed Hanif for your further comment and effort. I really appreciate it. Yes basically there might be an issue with the constraints. But the question is how do I have to set the constraints correctly. According to my point of view they are set correclty

Comment: How can I make sure that the layout editor displays the correct layout and not (as in my case) a false layout?

Comment: How can I make the layout independent of the device that displays it? Basically I always use dp and sp which should be device indepenent. However, changing the layout of the Emulator or LayoutEditor leads to different layouts. Do you know how I can solve these kind of issues?

Comment: Do you have any comments on my last 3 comments? I'd appreciate any further comment from you.

Comment: Hey the only option is to set the constraints properly. For eg :- you have your first textView50 with some margin and then your seekbar is in the center of the screen with some Horizontal bias so that in small screen size devices they might be too close and in karge screen devices or in portrait mode they might be too far from each other according to your margin. So that's the reason I suggested you to use the nested layouts in the first place.

Comment: Also i would suggest you to use ssp and sdp instead of sp and dp. You can find details here :- https://github.com/intuit/ssp

Comment: Thanks Mohammed Hanif for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. Is it somehow possible to scale a predefined layout to a larger screen? I have created many different layouts (about 20) using Constrained Layout but unfortunately they only look good at a 5' smartphone screen. I thought when using sp, dp and constrained layout the designed layout would be flexible

Comment: Do you know any good tutorial about how to make layouts for multiple screens using the constrained Layout? The official documentation of google (https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) is quite bad. It does not really explain how you should design your layout.

Comment: Any further comments? I'd highly appreciate it.

Comment: Hi. You can  have a look into this :- https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

Comment: Thanks Mohammed Hanif for your further comment. As already stated in  my last comment, I read this offical page and I think it is extremely bad (I posted the same link as you did). It does not explain how you should design your layout. I was asking for a tutorial/webpage that explains how you should design your layout using constrained layout such that thee layout looks good on different sceen sizes. The tutorial should be better than this (in my opinion) bad android developer page

Comment: How do I know how to set the constraints and the margins of each component in a constraintLayout such that the layout scales to different screen sizes?

Comment: You should always give constraint with respect to other views for example if you have one textfield at the center of the screen then you should give other textfield with respect to that if possible so that they both looks at same position in different  screens and if you move the first textfield then other textfields update accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Mohammed Hanif for your answer and effort. I really appreciate your valuable help. I have 2 questions regarding your comment: 1)  How shall I set the constraints to other views? Every item has 4 possible constraints. How do I know how many of them and which way I should use (destination of the constraints)? 2) What about the size of buttoms, textViews and ImageViews? How can I design them such that they scale to the current layout size. If you fix a size it won't scale however when not fixing you have to define some constraints. I do not understand how to do this

Comment: for your first question please look check my answer again in that I have set bottom and top constraints with respect to your seekbar so that they are aligned in same manner. similarly you should try to manage as much as possible constraints w.r.t to other views. for your second question you can use sdp and ssp.

Comment: Thanks Mohammed Hanif for your further answer and support.In your exmaple you just set the bottom and top constraints. But what about the horizontal constraints to the left and to the right. Which approach would you advice me to choose for setting those constraints? Regarding the sdp and ssp: I do not want to use any third party library but just officially acknoledged and evaluated elements from Android. As far as I know your posted githut link is nothing offical and thus I can't imagine that this is best pratice for high-quality Android development. How can I set the size in a recommended way

Comment: Any further comments to my last comment? I'd highly appreciate it, as I do not know what to do.

Comment: How do I have to set the constraints and margins?

Comment: Thanks Mohammed Hanif for your great help and effort. I accepted your answer